# Convert .CSV to HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv

I want to convert a **.csv file to a HTML Table in jQuery**. To accomplish that, I'm using a jQuery Plugin called [CSVToTable](https://code.google.com/p/jquerycsvtotable/).

The way I used it in my code is as follow:

I called the `.CSVToTable('path/to/file.csv')` on my `<div id="ItemTable"></div>`:

```
$("#ItemTable").CSVToTable('ItemDatabase.csv', {
  loadingImage: 'img/loading.gif',
  startLine: 0
});
```

Everything seemed to work, as well as the loading.gif (which was included in the download).

My first try was running it on the ItemDatabase.csv, which is a .csv that contains approx. 350 lines. **It kept loading and loading**, and after 15 minutes, I tried it with a smaller file that contains 5 lines. It made no difference.

I looked at the source of **[their website with a demo](http://honestbleeps.com/csvtotable/demo.html)**, which worked fine, replaced the code, but made no difference.

If somebody could tell me what I'm doing wrong, that would be very helpful.

Note: I checked the file paths, and everything is initialized correctly

EDIT: For @sakir, the first 4 lines of my .csv file:

```
Name,Tier,Kind,Lvl,mDam,xDam,HR,MR,SD,LS,MS,XB,LB
Depressing Bow,Depressing,Bow,1,0,0,NONE,NONE,NONE,NONE,NONE,NONE,NONE
Oak Wood Bow,Basic,Bow,1,4,6,NONE,NONE,NONE,NONE,NONE,NONE,NONE
Birch Wood Bow,Basic,Bow,6,6,10,NONE,NONE,NONE,NONE,NONE,NONE,NONE
```

Comment: is there any `javascript` error?

Comment: did you give any heaDER

Comment: @silk_route11 It throws out this error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///G:/Webs/WynnTools/test.csv. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. /G:/Webs/WynnTools/index.html:1`

Comment: @sakir Yes, it has a header

Comment: start line should be 1 if u have header I guess

Comment: * headers      - an array of headers for the CSV data
 *              - if not specified, plugin assumes that the first line of the CSV
 *                file contains the header names.

Comment: @sakir I also have a `<nav></nav>`, from Bootstrap. I didn't really understand what the `startLine` meant, this is directly copied from the source of their website with a demo, which can be found [here](http://honestbleeps.com/csvtotable/demo.html).

Comment: @sakir Eh, it's a 389 line .csv, and it's not uploaded. I don't think it fits in the topic, this huge amount of data.. (I can assure you, it's just a properly working .csv)

Comment: please take a look http://code.google.com/p/jquerycsvtotable/ .if you have not checked this yet..

Comment: not all just first 4 line :))

Comment: I ma looking source code of thiss link u have sent

Comment: @sakir Added the first 4 lines of my .csv file to my post.

Comment: you need "" for text,i guss

Comment: @sakir I tried the same file, but then with an online `.csv` to HTML Table converter (just as a test if the `.csv` actually worked), and it just did it's job correctly. No errors, and everything was working, even if I put the table in my `.html` file. So it has nothing to do with `""`, because the separator is set to `,`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use file from the local-file system. Please copy your file on the web-server and provide the url to that file in the .CSVToTable(url_file).

Comment: I am going to try this ASAP, thanks for the quick response! For now I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: @Pranav Maniar I tried this (using the .csv file from the demo), but it didn't work. It kept giving the error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///G:/Webs/WynnTools/data/ItemDatabase_clean.csv. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.` Any idea what would be the fix? D:

Comment: @Semx11 .. Please try to access the html-page using the web-server url.. For example if the index.html file is kept on csvtohtml folder of web-servler and server is running on port 80 then access it using url like `http://localhost/csvtohtml/index.html` .. If you are not doing this and instead directly running the file by double clicking it then you will get the above error...

Answer (score 0):

Try this way mate.But be sure to load required javascript and path to csv file.Inform me if it works for.Best of luck

csv file structure(test.csv)

```
Name,Tier,Kind,Lvl,mDam,xDam,HR,MR,SD,LS,MS,XB,LB
Depressing Bow,Depressing,Bow,1,0,0,NONE,NONE,NONE,NONE,NONE,NONE,NONE
Oak Wood Bow,Basic,Bow,1,4,6,NONE,NONE,NONE,NONE,NONE,NONE,NONE
Birch Wood Bow,Basic,Bow,6,6,10,NONE,NONE,NONE,NONE,NONE,NONE,NONE
```

code to  convert csv 2 table

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery CSVToTable</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/csvtable.css" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.csvToTable.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
 CSV To Table:<br>
<div id="CSVTable">

</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
            $('#CSVTable').CSVToTable('test.csv');
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this wasn't the issue. You probably copied this from the source of the demo, which I already inspected. Apparently the issue was that this plugin can't use local files, it needs an http://.

Thanks for the quick response, sadly I can't upvote your post yet, since I made my account today and I haven't got the required 15rep yet :/

Comment: Its ok mate, but i have used your csv file as local file, and its works fine. you can see the snap shot here http://i60.tinypic.com/29ndws6.png

Comment: Did you use it on a webserver? Like localhost? Or did you use it in Chrome/Firefox with file://? What browser were you using?

Comment: Mozila Firefox 27.0.1 with webserver like localhost/csv2table/index.html @Semx11

Comment: Exactly, a webserver. I'm just trying it with file://, which doesn't work. I have figured out the issue. It's Chrome (or FireFox) that doesn't allow file access from files. I had to start up Chrome with the flag "--allow-file-access-from-files", and now it does work. I did this for my 'developer workspace', but when I'll publish it, I'm going to move it on a webserver. Or something. I'll see :3 Thanks for the help :)