# Loading csv data into HTML div

Tags: javascript, html, css, csv

I have the following div

```
<div class="menu">
```

Additionally, I have a csv file that contains a bunch of strings called data.csv. For each string in this csv file I want to append a div into this menu div. For example say the csv contains the following data:

```
item_id, user_name
0,user1
1,user2
2,user3
```

Then, I am trying to read the data into two arrays and make the HTML look as follows:

```
<div class="menu">
  <div class="item" data-value="0">user1</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="1">user2</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="2">user3</div>
</div>
```

Here, each div inside the menu div has a data-value of the item_id and shows the text in this div as the user_name.

I have been trying approaches such as:

1.) [Loading a CSV file into an HTML table using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494032/loading-a-csv-file-into-an-html-table-using-javascript)

2.) https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/displaying-specific-data-from-a-csv-file/208326/6

but I am not a frequent javascript user and am having some trouble. Any tips or tricks for doing so would be great.

**Current Approach:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
// AJAX in the data file
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.csv",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {processData(data);}
    });

function processData(data) {
    var lines = data.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    var id = [];
    var name = [];
    var headings = lines[0].split(',');
    for (var j=1; j<lines.length; j++) {
    var values = lines[j].split(',');
       id.push(values[0]);
       name.push(values[1]); 
    }

}
})
</script>
```

I am using this to try and read the csv data into the id array and the name array, but am having trouble getting these to create a string that has the div with class and value and append it to the . There are about 2000 items in the csv file so I am wondering the best way to do this in javascript. I know how to do this in flask using jinja2, but am trying to learn javascript. The goal is to read the csv data into a dropdown menu.

Comment: Show us what you have already done

Comment: Added what I am trying right now!

Answer (score 2):

**CSV to dropdown**

If you want to read you data and access it as an option, a given in your question, you can user `ajax` request to fetch your file and on successfully fetching, you can process your request!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "test.csv",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      processData(data);
    }
  });
});

function processData(allText) {
  var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
  var options = $("#options");
  for (var i = 1; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
    var data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
    options.append($("<option />").val(data[0]).text(data[1]));
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Select user name: <select id='options'></select>
```

**CSV to html table**

With test.csv as your sample file, you can use csv to html jquery plugin!

You can download it from [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquerycsvtotable/source/default/source)

```js
$(function() {$('#csv_data').CSVToTable('test.csv');});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.csvToTable.js"></script>

CSV to html(table)<br>
<div id="csv_data">
</div>
```

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221112/convert-csv-to-html-table) for more info!

Comment: Does this only work for tables or can I create a custom div to put in my menu div from it?

Comment: I've edited my answer to get the data to a dropdown menu!